# how to convert array string to date swift 3

Tags: swift3, nsdateformatter

I have an array, `calendarFromDateArr` that is as follows:

```
["2017-10-30T07:41:00", "2017-10-30T11:23:00", "2017-10-30T11:48:00", "2017-11-10T00:00:00", "2017-11-13T19:43:00", "2017-12-01T00:00:00", "2017-12-31T00:00:00"]
```

I am using this code but `dateObjects` are `nil`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let dateObjects = self.calendarFromDateArr2.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }

print(dateObjects)

var dateObjects = [Date]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
for date in self.calendarFromDateArr2 {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateObjects.append(dateObject!)

    print(dateObjects)
}
```

I am using this code also but data is `nil`.

Comment: In addition to removing the `Z` and setting the `timeZone` property, as cldrr points out below, also set `locale` to `en_US_POSIX`, e.g. `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`, pursuant to [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Also, unrelated, in second half of your question, avoid setting `dateFormat` inside the loop. Setting `dateFormat` (or instantiating new date formatters) is very expensive, so avoid doing it in a loop if you can. In this case, just set the format string once before the loop and you're golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're dateFormat string is wrong, you don't have a zone in your date strings (the Z stands for the time zone: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

This example here works perfectly fine:

```
let dates =  ["2017-10-30T07:41:00", "2017-10-30T11:23:00", "2017-10-30T11:48:00", "2017-11-10T00:00:00", "2017-11-13T19:43:00", "2017-12-01T00:00:00", "2017-12-31T00:00:00"]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let dateObjects = dates.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }

print(dateObjects)
```

Output:

```
[2017-10-30 07:41:00 +0000, 2017-10-30 11:23:00 +0000, 2017-10-30 11:48:00 +0000, 2017-11-10 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-11-13 19:43:00 +0000, 2017-12-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-12-31 00:00:00 +0000]
```